# Information source on safety for Kiev visitors

Tags: planning, safety, ukraine, event-based-effects

I may have to visit Kiev (unless my ministry for foreign affairs say otherwise) for a meeting. I am not going anywhere in Eastern Ukraine. Where can I find the best source on safety for travellers? 
Edit: I have an interpreter. I plan to stay in or near Kiev.

Comment: How's your Russian or Ukrainian?

Comment: And further where in Ukraine do plan to go?

Answer (score 9):

I spent the weekend in Kiev a few weeks ago and it was nothing like what I expected.

Had it not been for the BBC coverage of the events with Russia I would not have had a clue that this was a country essentially at war.

My only advice would be around currency. I could not for the life of me get currency at home (UK) and had to do it when I landed in Kiev. I would however also take a small amount in a stronger currency as well (GBP, USD or EURO) as these are generally accepted and sometimes preferred. If like me you land too late to exchange currency you can either pay with a stronger one or with draw from a cash machine.

As I said in and around Kiev you should be perfectly safe. It wouldn't hurt to keep the embassy details in your phone just in case. In terms of how much money to take, Ukraine is very cheap and I wouldn't take that much money. My hotel cost me £56 for 4 days and it was fine.

This is the link I used to keep an eye on the situation [UK Gov Ukraine Travel Advice](https://www.gov.uk/foreign-travel-advice/ukraine)

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the [US Department of State travel advisories](http://travel.state.gov/content/passports/english/country/ukraine.html) and the [Canadian equivalent](http://travel.gc.ca/destinations/ukraine) should give you a pretty good assessment of the situation for a typical business trip.

Comment: Actually for situations as fluid as the current one in Ukraine the only real information is from the locals.

Comment: @Karlson the Canadian warning includes "last updated" and "valid until" fields. Are you saying to be sure to check these, or are you suggesting that even a report updated yesterday and still considered valid by the issuer is likely to be inaccurate?

Comment: @KateGregory The problem with these reports is that they only include major events like situation in Donetsk, Luhansk, Crimea and Kharkov and don't consider regions bordering Crimea or Russian in the North.  Secondly based on the information from Kharkov the visitors that don't participate in the political rallies have nothing to worry about by day.  Night is slightly different story.

Comment: @Karlson: This is true, at present at least. I live in Kharkiv.

Comment: I am from Kharkiv, kov. But I still keep in touch with my former classmates.

Comment: @Roman (and Karlsson), According to last week’s issue of the newspaper the Economist, “local Russian supporters“ occupied Kharkiv’s opera house thinking it was the building of the municipal council, citing this as proof  that  the supporters were anything but local. Do you know anything about this?

Comment: @MikaelJensen: This is a story from Apr 07 ([Source, in Russian](http://echo.msk.ru/blog/echomsk/1295362-echo/)), to my best knowledge it is fake. Funny but fake. We have lots of these nowadays.

Comment: @Karlson They tend to be conservative in their advice but if you read between the lines, the Canadian advisory says exactly the same. “There is no nationwide advisory in effect for Ukraine.” and, regarding, Kharkiv, “Avoid large crowds and facilities associated with political parties or activists.” Avoid *non-essential* travel is also code for the area is not at war/foreigners are not specifically targeted. Reports about other countries certainly do take into account the info consulates get from stranded tourists (e.g. about regular criminality) and are not limited to major events.

Comment: @RomanR. Haven't seen your comment on the subject.  The story isn't fake.  There is a video made in front of the theater right before what was described in the article.  Same was confirmed by my friends in Kharkov(kiv).

Comment: @Relaxed Avoiding large crowds is always pretty good advice everywhere (a crowd of football fans after a loss could be dangerous).   What I am suggesting still stands reading between the lines or otherwise.  Locals have better information then the diplomatic services or consulates.

Comment: @Karlson: It was someone's prank, if ever happened at all. For over a year we've been fed with stories "how stupid separatists are".

Comment: @Karlson You can believe what you want but since your *specific* criticism does not actually apply to the content of the advisory, what's your evidence that there is any problem at all with these reports? Beyond that, I don't think anecdotes are generally such a good guide to anything. Case in point: This comments' thread features two people with an apparently genuine claim to be locals and they can't agree. Any given local can only generally provide a very incomplete picture and might not completely realize what's risky for foreigners or not.

Comment: @Relaxed My criticism is that they are overly concervative and meant as a general cautionary note to all not to venture to certain areas.  The problem is that it doesn't necessarily mean that safe passage cannot be obtained through the affected areas that's why you need local guidance, which has more up to date information about safety of various areas.

Comment: @Karlson But who is saying that safe passage cannot be obtained or that you should go there without local guidance? To me, that's exactly what “postpone non-essential travel” and “exercise a high degree of caution” means. Until now, everything you have been saying supports the travel advisory and the need to heed its advice so why be so dismissive?

Comment: @Relaxed Because a year ago the the situation in Ukraine was changing too rapidly to follow the official recommendations since any travel for purpose other than official government required or medically necessary is by definition: "*non-essential*".  So following your suggestion means: don't travel.  And BTW, the warnings currently posted are not exactly the same as was 1 year ago.

Comment: @Karlson Essential travels typically includes some business travel as well. The implication is that tourism might not be such a good idea but everybody is free to make their own determination. Above all, it means it's a tad more dangerous than other places and you should be prepared, which is also what you have been saying. And changes to the advisory are to be expected, if the situation is changing, as you have been very keen to stress all along. It seems you just don't like the idea and are looking for some pretexts to dismiss it but I find them thoroughly unconvincing.

Comment: Finally a situation that's changing very rapidly is in itself a very good reason to discourage travel and to follow the advice to postpone all but non-essential trips. Here again, what's your point?

Comment: @Relaxed My point is that the trip is already happenning.

Comment: @Karlson That's actually an excellent point! It's more useful to evaluate the overall risk of a trip, not as a planning tool if you decide you must go.

Answer (score 0):

The UK Foreign and Commonwealth Office issues travel advice: here is their page for [Ukraine](https://www.gov.uk/foreign-travel-advice/ukraine).

I'd be surprised if the Swedish Ministry for Foreign Affairs didn't do something similar, too.

Comment: We have something similar but it is fairly general, just as yours.